# setCanceledOnTouchOutside doesn't work when i tap just near the dialog on outside

Tags: android, touch, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog :

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,       AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
    ListAdapter adapter = new CustomDialogAdapter(context, itemsList);
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, listener);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

setCanceledOnTouchOutside is working only when i tap on a certain distance from the dialog.When i tap just near the dialog it doesn't get dismissed.Do you guys know a way to dismiss the dialog even when i tap just near the dialog?Thanks.

Comment: Try to call `.setCancelable(true)` just before to see what happens.

Comment: thanks for answer, I already did that but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Using AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT works if you want the dialog to be full screen. An alternative is to create your own style, like so:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);
    ListAdapter adapter = new CustomDialogAdapter(context, itemsList);
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, listener);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

have style.xml in values folder like below:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
<style name="ThemeDialogCustom" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

also add colors.xml in values folder:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="transparent_color">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

This is working for me. Hope it will works for you as well